# Shift img few pixels up or down

Tags: html, css

This seems trivial, but I cannot find anything.
I have a text and small image (icon) inside the text like this:

```
<span>ask<img src=ask.svg height=16> fav<img src=fav.svg> voted</span>
```

All I need is to move the image few pixels up or down to look better with the text.

I tried CSS styles like `margin-top:3px`, `padding-top:3px`, `display:absolute`, `display:relative` and some others, but nothing works.

**UPDATE**: I do not need vertical align to middle. Yes, it looks better, but I still want to be able to shift the image a few pixels manually. So my question remains: how to fine tune the image vertical position within the text by a few pixels in any direction.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried messing with vertical-align (css)?

Comment: span img {vertical-align:middle;} should be fine.

Comment: even if I use middle-align it is still not exactly what I want, I still want to shift few pixels more.

Comment: Use `vertical-align` with a pixel value rather than `middle`. e.g. `vertical-align:-3px`

Comment: @Alohci this works!! Can you make it into an answer and get your reputation?

Answer (score 7):

You can set `position: relative` for `img`, then move it with `top` or `bottom`
http://jsfiddle.net/kencoder97/xu4158fL/

An example to move an image upwards by a couple of pixels would be

```
<img src="my_image.jpg" style="position: relative; bottom: 2px">
```

Answer (score 0):

Note: margin-top not marginTop..same goes for padding etc. learn more about html and css syntax.

```
<span>ask<img src=ask.svg height="16" style="margin-Top:-6px">fav<img src=fav.svg> voted</span>
```

It's a good idea to take your image out of span tags,

```
  <span>ask</span><img src=ask.svg height="16" style="margin-Top:-6px"><span>fav</span><img src=fav.svg><span> voted</span>
```

or just use div for wrapper

```
<div>ask<img src=ask.svg height="16" style="margin-Top:-6px">fav<img src=fav.svg> voted</div>
```

Comment: use "div" instead of "span", or close and reopen span before/after images

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/v594fvgr/

```
span img {
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Comment: this works, but is not what I want, I still want to shift the image few pixels, perfectly middle-aligned image is not exactly what I want.